# How to filter data displayed in a table in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

[image: The table should get filtered when I click Filter Results button]I have a project where when a user enters a vehicle no, the database is filtered and a table containing that vehicle no and the information corresponding to is displayed. I further want to filter this displayed table, eg: if the user chooses to see quantity greater than 18kl, then the matching vehicle number with quantity greater than 18 is displayed. Also I want to hide the columns selected by the users as there are many columns. Can someone tell me how to do this in django, or suggest some better ways. (I am providing only the related code snippet.)

### forms.py

```
class VehicleSearch(forms.Form):
    vehicl[![enter image description here][1]][1]e_no = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special'}), required=False)

#filter form
class Filter(forms.Form):
    capacity_grp = forms.ChoiceField(label='Show only', widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                     choices=[('abv', '>18 kl'), ('blw', '<18 kl')], required=False)
```

### views.py

```
def search(request):
    form_1 = forms.VehicleSearch()
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'btnform1' in request.POST:
        form_1 = forms.VehicleSearch(request.POST)
        if form_1.is_valid():
            vehicle_no = form_1.cleaned_data['vehicle_no']
            transport = models.Transport.objects.filter(vehicle=vehicle_no)
            my_dict.update({'transport': transport})
    return render(request, 'search.html', my_dict)
```

### search.html

/*Vehicle form*/

```
        <form id="f1" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form_1.as_p}}
            <p style="padding: 10px;"><button class="myButton" name="btnform1">Search</button></p>
        </form>

/*Table display*/
<div class="submain">
    {% if transport %}
    <table id="transportation">
        <thead>
        <th>Vehicle</th>
        <th>Carrier</th>
        <th>Location No</th>
        <th>MCMU</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Customer Code</th>
        <th>Zone</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>RTKM</th>
        <th>KL* KM</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Load</th>
        <th>Capacity</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        </thead>
        {% for i in transport %}
        <tr class="item">
            <td>{{ i.vehicle }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.carrier }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.location_no }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.mcmu }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.location }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.customer_code }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.zone }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.quantity }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.rtkm }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.klkm }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.load }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.capacity }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.rate }}</td>
            <td>{{ i.cost }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the table display you can add a loop with the name's field, something like that:

**View**:

```
def search(request):
   form_1 = forms.VehicleSearch()
   if request.method == 'POST' and 'btnform1' in request.POST:
    form_1 = forms.VehicleSearch(request.POST)
    columns = request.POST.getlist('filter_hide_columns')
    if form_1.is_valid():
        vehicle_no = form_1.cleaned_data['vehicle_no']
        transport = models.Transport.objects.filter(vehicle=vehicle_no)
        my_dict.update({'transport': transport}, {'columns': columns})
  return render(request, 'search.html', my_dict)
```

**TemplateTag**

```
def lookup(model, attr):
    if hasattr(model, attr):
        return getattr(model, attr)
    else:
        return None
```

refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

**Template**:

```
{% if transport %}
     <table id="transportation">
        <thead>
           <tr>
             {% for field in columns %}
                <th>{{ field.name }}</th>
             {% endfor %}
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for t in transport %}
              <tr>
                 {% for field in columns %}
                     <td>{{ t|lookup:field.name }}</td>
                 {% endfor %}
              </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
     </table>
{% endif %}
```

Please refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Comment: can you tell me what changes will I have to make in the views.py

Comment: Updated one more